# Laravel valet park shows XAMPP main page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I am currently learning PHP Laravel. I am in the process of setting up valet. However, I encountered a problem. Whenever I type (filename).dev, it shows the XAMPP main page instead of the Laravel initial project page. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You are probably running a XAMPP server at the same time. Stop all the services (MySQL, PHP, Apache, XAMPP) and try re-running valet again.

Comment: Excellent!!! Just for completion, I will add that answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original answer can be found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/valet-v112-update-just-keep-getting-the-it-works).

- Remove valet completely (some reason valet uninstall does nothing) so to get the latest version (v1.1.3 at the time)
- Stop Apache: `apachectl stop`
- Update Valet: `composer global require laravel/valet`
- Install Valet: `valet install`
- Restart Valet: `valet restart`

With some others, it might be a good option to try and simply turn-off/stop your locally running Apache, as this as others might find is only the issue that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as I was running Xampp and Valet at the same time on my Windows Machine, try turning off the xampp/apache and run the page again.

Steps to install Valet on Windows..

1. Install composer from https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. Then run composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows
3. Then run: "valet install"
4. Open your Laravel project directory in cmd (administrator mode)
5. Then run: "valet park"
6. Then run: "valet link"
7. Then run: "valet secure" (if you want your website to be secured by TLS)
8. In the control panel/network and sharing center choose the active connection and in its properties enter 127.0.0.1 in TCP/IPv4 [IPv4 settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXyxQ.png)
9. In the control panel/network and sharing center choose the active connection and in its properties enter ::1 in TCP/IPv6 [IPv6 settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC6Su.png)
10. Then run: "valet start"
11. Enter the "projectname" followed by ".test" in the browser.
    For example: if your project name is demolaravel, then run demolaravel.test in the browser